# Sort a Dictionary by key AND value?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary

What if I want to sort a dictionary in C# with the order determined by its key AND its value. Like descending order by its value and within those having the same value, descending by its key. It seems quite possible to sort only by key or only by value, but by both is quite annoying.

Comment: It is impossible to sort dictionary, because dictionary stores data as a hash table internally and it can't be reordered. You have to convert it to List first

Comment: What is the purpose of sorting the key exactly?  You could use some besides a Dictionary and you could then sort both the key and value except I don't the purpose of that.  If you need a Sorted Collection using a Dictionary is a bad choice.

Comment: Please accept an aswer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 30):

```
using System.Linq;
...
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> sortedCollection = myDictionary
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: what is reason of last `ToDistionary`? dictionary **can't** be sorted. You destroy effect of ordering.

Comment: @Andrey I definitely should test my code before posting! You're right once again. ToDictionary doesn't make any sense at all. IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> should be sufficient anyway.

Comment: What @nawfal means is do use `var`.

Comment: @nawfal Thanks for the translation. I deliberately did not use `var` so that OP (and other, perhaps less experienced developers) can see the return type at first glance. I try to make my answers as helpful as possible, even if the resulting code sometimes isn't as idiomatic as it could be.

Comment: Ya I understand. I wasn't criticizing. Just a pointer to your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more complex ordering scheme, implement an IComparer> to use in the overloaded version of OrderBy or OrderByDescending.